# Modify files from maven library

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I'm developing my project using Android Studio and I have a library imported as module into my project with some xml files modified to fit my needs. My question is if there is a way of modifying those resource files if I add the library as a maven dependency or it can be done only by adding it as a module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a library as a Maven dependency, e.g.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.foo:1.0.0'
}
```

it's going to download that dependency from the Maven repository in whatever format is specified in the artifact, typically JAR or AAR. If it's downloading a prebuilt library like that, you can't make any local changes to it.

If you need to make changes, your best bet is to include it as a module instead of a Maven-style dependency like that. However, if this is a common library that will be shared among multiple projects, you have a number of options to make that sharing easier. You could build it as a library and include it in your projects via that Maven-style include (perhaps deploying the library to a local or organization-wide repository), or if it suits you better, you could put the library in a common place on local disk and reference it in-place via your **settings.gradle** file.